# How does the createReadStream() works in aws-sdk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, stream, aws-sdk

I'd like to use `s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(writableStream)` to directly write in the fs an object from s3 (the aim is to lower the RAM use).
My concern is really about the price, i have no idea how it works and want to avoid multiples `GET` calls against s3 which may be expensive.

My guess is that HTTP requests already works similarly like streams using raw data packet and aws-sdk just wrap it in a node stream. But another possibility would be to request consecutively parts of the object and therefore using several GET calls.

My searches were unsuccessful, do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The use of streams doesn't affect the price, it just changes the way you are going to handle the incoming data.

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const source = s3.getObject({ Key: 'key', Bucket: 'bucket-name' }).createReadStream();
const target = fs.createWriteStream('/your/local/path/to/store/the/object');
source.pipe(target).on('end', () => {
  console.log('Object stored...')
  // Custom code here...
})
.on('error', err => {
  console.log('Something went wrong...')
  // Custom code here...
})
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi @Antonio, thank you for your answer. You answered about the price yes (which i'd like to confirm to not be fired ^^), but i would be very interested in how it works, how the sdk manage to stream the incoming data...

Comment: According to AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/requests-using-stream-objects.html), it's just one HTTP request and you get the raw data. So I think you shouldn't care about managing multiple HTTP requests because it's not case...